# Ошибка в C++ , связанная с типом данных

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

void main()

{

    float d, b, z;
    setlocale(0, "Russian");
    printf("\nВведите два катета");
    scanf_s("%f %f", d, b);
    z = sqrt(d*d + b*b);
    printf("Площадь равна=");
    printf(0, 5 * d*b);
    printf("Периметр равен=");
    printf(d + b + z);
}
```

Visual Studio выдает ошибку:

```
Ошибка  C2664   "int printf(const char *const ,...)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "float" в "const char *const " ConsoleApplication22    c:\users\79582\source\repos\consoleapplication22\consoleapplication22\consoleapplication22.cpp  20
```

Comment: `printf(0, 5 * d*b);` [printf](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/printf) принимает строку, а не float

Comment: iostream включен аж два раза - зачем пытаться использовать printf как ostream?

Comment: [Учите матчасть](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) - в смысле того, что первой в вызове идет строка формата...

Comment: Для переносимости у `main` должен быть возвращаемый тип `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начнём с заголовочных файлов. Вместо стандартных заголовочных файлов вида <*name*.h> лучше использовать заголовочные файлы вида <*cname*>, т.к. первые признаны устаревшими и могут быть удалены в будущих версиях стандарта языка C++. Итак, нам понадобятся:

`<cstdio>` для `std::printf` и `std::scanf`
`<clocale>` для `std::setlocale` и макроса `LC_ALL`
`<cmath>` для `std::sqrt`

Функция `main` должна возвращать значение типа `int`. Может ли она возвращать значение какого-нибудь другого типа или нет определяется реализацией, поэтому объявим `main` так:

```
int main()
```

Первым аргументом в функцию `std::setlocale` лучше передать один из специально предназначенных для этого [макросов](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/LC_categories). Например, `LC_ALL`. Учтите, что одно и тоже целочисленное значение в разных компиляторах может соответствовать разным макросам. Например, в [gcc](https://ideone.com/3bAs85) `0` соответствует макросу `LC_CTYPE`, в то время как в [vc++](https://rextester.com/PYMF40749) `0` соответствует макросу `LC_ALL`.

В C++ в отличие от языка C функция `scanf_s` не обязана быть объявлена в каком-либо заголовочном файле, поэтому лучше воспользоваться [функцией `std::scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf). Спецификатор `%f` говорит, что в `scanf` необходимо передать **указатель** на `float`:

```
std::scanf("%f %f", &d, &b);
```

Первым аргументом в [функцию `std::printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) необходимо передать указатель на начальный символ нуль-терминированной строки, задающей что собственно необходимо отобразить и как интерпретировать последующие аргументы. Чтобы вывести значение типа `float` можно воспользоваться спецификатором преобразования `%f`:

```
std::printf("Площадь равна = %f", 0.5 * d * b);
```

Обратите внимание, что разделитель целой и дробной частей в литерале с плавающей точкой — это точка (`.`). Итоговый код выглядит [примерно так](https://ideone.com/tdD9lZ):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <clocale>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    float d, b, z;
    
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    std::printf("Введите два катета: ");
    std::scanf("%f %f", &d, &b);
    z = std::sqrt(d*d + b*b);
    std::printf("Площадь равна = %f\n", 0.5 * d * b);
    std::printf("Периметр равен = %f\n", d + b + z);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    double d, b, z, S, P;
    setlocale(0, "Russian");
    std::cout << "Введите катет: ";
    std::cin >> d;
    std::cout << "Введите второй катет: ";
    std::cin >> b;
    z = sqrt(d * d + b * b);
    S = 0.5 * d * b;
    P = d + b + z;
    std::cout << "Площадь равна: " << S << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Периметр равен: " << P << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Решение задачи средствами С++ - это бонус к ответу. Его основой лучше сделать объяснение причины возникшей ошибки и способ её исправления, потому что сейчас это не похоже на ответ.